# Login con Value Objects sin usar todos los campos de la tabla

Tags: php, pdo

Estoy haciendo un `login` y en el `VO` utilizo `setter` y `getters`. 
En el `DAO` al hacer la consulta solo invoco a tres campos, pero al tratar de grabarlo en el objeto `UsuarioVO` me muestra

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function getUsuario()

**UsuarioVO.php**

```
class usuarioVO{
    private $usuario;
    private $clave;
    private $privilegio;
    private $estado;
    private $idpersona;

public function getUsuario(){
    return $this->usuario;
}

public function setUsuario($usuario){
    $this->usuario = $usuario;
}

public function getClave(){
    return $this->clave;
}

public function setClave($clave){
    $this->clave = $clave;
}

public function getPrivilegio(){
    return $this->privilegio;
}

public function setPrivilegio($privilegio){
    $this->privilegio = $privilegio;
}

public function getEstado(){
    return $this->estado;
}

public function setEstado($estado){
    $this->estado = $estado;
}

public function getIdpersona(){
    return $this->idpersona;
}

public function setIdpersona($idpersona){
    $this->idpersona = $idpersona;
}
}
```

**UsuarioDAO.php**

```
class UsuarioDAO{

public function __construct(){
}

public function login($usuario, $clave){
    try {
            $query = "SELECT usuario, privilegio, estado FROM sc_usuario WHERE usuario = :usuario AND clave = :clave";

            $BD = new ConexionDB();
            $resultado = $BD->prepare($query);
            $resultado->bindParam(":usuario", $usuario, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $resultado->bindParam(':clave', $clave, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $resultado->execute();

            $usuario = NULL;
            while ($fila = $resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $usuario = new UsuarioVO($fila[getUsuario()], $fila[getPrivilegio()], $fila[getEstado()]);
            }
            return $usuario;

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            die ('No se puede ejecutar la consulta');
        }
}

function __destruct(){
}
```

}

**login.php**

```
if (($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") && ($_POST['action'] === 'login')){
    if (isset($_POST['usuario']) && isset($_POST['clave'])) {
        $usuariodao = new UsuarioDAO();
        $user = $usuariodao->login($_POST['usuario'], $_POST['clave']);

    if(isset($user)){
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario; // env[ia a usuario a sesion
        $_SESSION['logueado'] = 1;  // control de ingreso
        header("Location: index.php?action=main"); // lanza pantalla principal
        exit;
    } else {
        $tpl = new Plantilla();
        $tpl->assign('errorLogin', "Usuario y/o Clave incorrectos");
        $tpl->display("login.tpl.php");
    }
}
}

header("Location: index.php");
```

**formulario.html**

```
<form action="index.php?action=login" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usuario" name="usuario" placeholder="Nombre de Usuario" required>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="clave" name="clave" placeholder="Contraseña" required>
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="login">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Iniciar Sesión</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error parece sencillo , en está línea

```
$usuario = new UsuarioVO($fila[getUsuario()], $fila[getPrivilegio()], $fila[getEstado()]);
```

Estas construyendo un objeto de la clase `UsuarioVO` , pero dentro de los parámetros enviados hace una llamada a una función inexistente de la clase `login.php` lo cuál es incorrecto ya que solo existe en `UsuarioVO`,  Así exista intenta acceder al resultado de la consulta realizada. Lo correcto sería como `fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` retorna `array` con los nombres de la columna sería solo acceder a estos indices.

```
$usuario = new UsuarioVO($fila['usuario'], $fila['privilegio'], $fila['estado']);
```

*(puede tener estas funciones tal y como está también, pero sus funciones deben estar en `login.php` y retornar solo el string con los nombres de las columnas de su consulta)* pero no es tan conveniente tener código así.

```
function getUsuario(){
    return 'usuario';
}
```

Comment: Y por qué se recomienda usar setter y getters, pensé usarlos en este caso.

Comment: No puede usarlos antes de tener un objeto creado de la clase _(UsuarioVO)_ , Luego de crear ya podrá utilzarlos . Las [ventajas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8955492/6502043) de utilizar son varias pero iríamos lejos de la pregunta central. Tal cuál está mi respuesta debería solucionar su error.